# What is the installation directory for the Aptana Studio 3 IDE?

Tags: ide, installation, aptana

Call me stupid but I just can't find the installation directory for this program. I checked both the Program Files and Program Files (x86) folders in my C drive and can't find anything with Apatana in the folder name. Anyone know where this program installs itself?

Comment: What'd it say during setup? What path did you specify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can see a shortcut or link to the Aptana program, then right click on the icon and select Properties. That should show you where it points to.

Comment: I became very confused because Aptana did't create a shortcut in the start menu/page (argh!). I was like hey, Aptana, where did you go!? Later on, I found a shortcut on my desktop.

My aptana was located at "c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio"

(windows 8.1)

Comment: Very weird location, indeed.

Comment: It didn't create a shortcut on the desktop

Answer (score 10):

Aptana Studio 3 by default is installed in Users directory. To be precise in:
C:/Users/Default/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3

Remember to unhide hidden folders.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 8 it's in : 
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio

Comment: Quite the same in Windows 7. On my Windows 7 64 bit machine, I found it correspondingly in C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio. There then was a file called AptanaStudio3.exe which starts Aptana Studio, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I found it here:

```
C:\Users\[Your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio
```

Once you're there you can right-click on it and "Pin" it if you're in Win 8.

I agree, the installation process doesn't clarify this.

Comment: It would be helpful if the actual application launched after it was installed, or if the dialog asked where you wanted to install it. Also, as I ran the installation as an administrator, the program is now only visible to the administrator account. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have installed Aptana using your admin account and cannot see it on your normal account**

1. Go to C:\Users[Your admin user name]\AppData\Roaming\
2. Right-click on the Appcelerator folder
3. Select cut
4. Go to C:\Users[Your user name]\AppData\Roaming\
5. Right-click, select paste
6. Go into C:\Users[Your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio
7. right click on the orange application icon
8. select copy
9. right-click on desktop
10. select 'Paste Shortcut'

(NB: AppData is an 'invisible' folder, so you will have to type or paste in the file path)

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio Windows 10 folder location:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.exe